# Strange Event in Google calendar

Tags: google-calendar, spam-prevention

> ⏳ПОДТВЕРДИТЕ ПОЛУЧЕНИЕ ДЕНЕЖНОЙ ВЫПЛАТЫ. Уведомление от Центра Безопасных Электронных Платежей. Вам начислена денежная компенсация. Получите денежные средства сегодня ➡ [spam link]

This is the event I got. It's for ages. This is a SPAM. What can I do to remove this? This event added for ages. I can't remove this.

Comment: What do you mean with *It's for ages*? BTW I have edited out the link, we don't people to click on spam links.

Comment: Along with what @JanDoggen said can you also clarify what you mean by that you cannot remove it? If the event is from another calendar you have added that is synced from a URL you will not be able to remove the event, however you can remove or hide the calendar. For example I have a shift website where I can take work shifts and those shifts are in a calendar synced with my Gcal. The calendar entries will say which calendar they are from: "Computer Locus's shifts". I cannot remove them as its a synced calendar

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of hours ago. No idea how the event reached my calendar. Probably a severe bug somewhere. It is basically an invitation for a Hangouts call, every day at the same time, without final date.

To remove it from the calendar, I just clicked on edit, and removed all the events. That erased them, but since I don't know how it reached my calendar, I'm not sure how to prevent it from happening again.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a new issue, and is something that comes up every once in awhile. It's basically exploiting the default settings of Calendar to automatically add invitations to the calendar and/or leave declined events on the calendar. If you change your settings to turn those off, you should be protected.

More information:

- [InfoSecurity - Criminals Try to Schedule Spam in Google Calendar](https://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/news/criminals-try-to-schedule-spam-in-1/)
- [PCMag - Don't Get Duped by This Sneaky Google Calendar Spam](https://www.pcmag.com/g00/news/369046/dont-get-duped-by-this-sneaky-google-calendar-spam)
- [Lifehacker - How to Keep Spam Out of Your Google Calendar](https://lifehacker.com/how-to-keep-spam-out-of-your-google-calendar-1835810050)